# How to open specific branch of git repo in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to see the files of particular branch of my repo. How can I open that file in intellij.
When I am trying to open repo in intellij it is showing code of master branch.
pls Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick option here, which doesn't require actually checking out another branch, would be to right click the file of interest and then choose:

```
Git => Compare with branch...
```

This will bring up a dialog listing all branches for your current repository.  You may choose the branch of interest.  This in turn will launch a side-by-side window showing both the version from the current branch (presumably `master`) right next to the version from the branch you have chosen.

Going this route might actually be what you want, if your intention be to compare a given file in the current branch against a version in another branch.

Comment: what if the file is removed in the current branch?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you have multiple branches exp.- branch1, branch2,branch3
and you can open a particular  branch file,
checkout particular branch & open file easily
**CMD= git checkout branch1**